# django models field factory

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-descriptors

I am trying to do something like this:

```
    class User(models.Model):
        @staticmethod                                                                                                                                                                                               
        def NameField():                                                                                                                                                                                            
            return models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
        name = NameField.__get__(None, object)
```

And when I create instance of User, passing some name to the constructor python throws an error:

```
    TypeError: 'name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

What is going on? How I can make factories for model fields?

Comment: What are you doing with `__get__`? You don't do that on a normal field. Why not just `name = NameField()`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the point? A field represents a database column, why would you want a factory for it?

Comment: @CoryMadden I tried to just call NameField, didn't work

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand why you want to do this.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to use this field in several models, so if I want to change it, I won't rewrite code in several files

Comment: Then the thing to do is to define a subclass of CharField which sets the relevant parameters in its `__init__` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Didn't think about that, thank you